# How do I add a news ticker in Google Visualization api (geo chart)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

I use the Google Visualization API (geo chart) which is refreshing every 5 sec. I need to add a news sticker which refreshes every 1 minute regardless of the API refreshing time. And I need to display data in this sticker from database. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you can already update the chart every 5 second, why can't you schedule the sticker updates into it?

Comment: I dont want sticker to update every 5 seconds. I want it to update regardless of Google API updation time. And how to display values from database in sticker?